# Sorted associative array swift 3.0

Tags: swift, sorting, swift3, associative-array

I tried to sort an associative array in swift i have one array :

```
var score : [String : Int] = [String : Int]()
```

I want to sort this by the value (Int) i try func sorted() but this return [(key: Key, value: Value)] and i obtain this error :

```
 Cannot convert value of type '[(key: String, value: Int)]' to specified type '[String : Int]'
```

with this code :

```
let retour : [String : Int] = score.sorted(by: {backward($0.1, $1.1)} )
```

I understand the error but I don't know how I can sort associative array and obtain the type of instances who call sort func in return.

So i do this :

```
        let sortedArray = score.sorted(by: {backward($0.1, $1.1)} )

        var sortedScore : [String : Int] = [String : Int]()

        for (key,value) in sortedArray {
            print("Key : \(key) | Value : \(value)")
            sortedScore[key] =  value
        }


       func backward(_ s1: Int, _ s2: Int) -> Bool {
           return s1 < s2
       }
```

My sortedArray arrays is sorted but my sortedScore is not sorted after loop. And during the loop the print value is sorted. I really don't understand. 
Thank you

Comment: You can not sort dictionary,

Comment: But if i do this : `retour = score.sorted{$0.1 > $1.1}` i obtain a array [(key: Key, value: Value)]  sorted by value.

Comment: @gabrielpf It's no longer a a dictionary, is it?